# Quantum Crosstalk in gate scheduling with different gates

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit, superconducting-quantum-computing

I am working on quantum crosstalk, specifically on **CNOT** and **SWAP** gate operations that lead to crosstalk. I have encountered works that ***decompose CNOT and SWAP with iSWAP and CZ gates***. I would like to know if executing these decomposed gates of CNOT and SWAP in parallel will or will not lead to crosstalk. The reason for parallel execution is decoherence. So what are the ways to reduce decoherence when trying to minimise crosstalk?

I am planning to execute this idea on an IBM Q Falcon processor.

Comment: Crosstalk is highly dependent on the system, and another point to consider is that, usually, you can only perform specific gates on the hardware. When you submit the job, the compiler will decompose your circuit to a native gate set to that system when you execute the circuit. Is [this article](https://research.ibm.com/blog/eagle-quantum-processor-performance) and the citations provided are of any help?